# Dynamic Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i need to create dynamic jasper report .

my scenario is i have nearly 60 tables in database,so i can't create 60 jasper reports.i want a template jasper report which should be modified automatically  by program.The data will come dynamically from the database and will be stored in  an arraylist.
iterating the arraylist i need to upload the data to jasper report.
is that possible in java + jasper Reports.
if so please give an example or any idea.

thanks
pramod

Answer (score 4):

Through DynamicReports you can create dynamic reports quickly and easily. 
Take a look at following [step by step](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to achieve this directly from JasperReports without having to learn to use another library have a look at the following tutorial available [here](http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/how-to-dynamically-modify-a-jasperreports-report).

Answer (score 1):

[DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) (DJ) is the best and more well - documented solution in my opinion. It offers every feature of DynamicReports but also includes Struts2 and WebWork integration and a clean excel report. Read more at the site.

Comment: They dont allow you to position your subreports. Also their documentation is poor.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I have taken other than what @jeshurun has mentioned, is outlined in the following [post](http://broschb.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-jasper-report-using-crosstabs.html).  Both of these approaches have worked for me depending on what I needed.