# JasperReports: dynamic report generation

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports*. I need to design a report where certain columns and rows are dynamic. For this how I have to design the report and after design i want to integrate with my application for fetching data from action class and dto. How to map data for its?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936068/how-to-create-a-dynamic-report-thorough-jrxml & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947467/dynamic-jasper-report

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how dynamic it will be, but it may help you: http://dynamicjasper.com/

It uses JasperReports to generate your report and it also allow you to create your report on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to map data with the columns. First option is u can pass ur data into data Source binding with the column name as key value pair. And the second option is u can pass the obj of your dto to data source directly in list form.
Use report.setDataSource() for setting the data. In first option make sure your type of the data matches with the column name.